# How to get a list of the dockwidgets in a QDockWidgetArea?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

To add a QDockWidget to a window, you need to call `addDockWidget(area, *widget)`

where `area` is a [Qt::DockWidgetArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#dockWidgetArea).

My question is, after adding QDockWidgets to an area, is it possible to get a list of all the QDockWidgets in that area?

Of course, one could just use `QObject::findChild<QDockWidget>`, iterate through the results, and then use `QMainWindow::dockWidgetArea(widget)` to compile a list of all the widgets in the desired area.

But I want to know if there is a better way? Seems like a "getDockWidgetsInArea" function should already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Why not overriding [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) ? You could make your own `addDockWidget` function and create a `getDockWidgetsInArea` function as well.